# jqgrid viewGridRow() not updating all fields on row change

Tags: jqgrid

I'm initializing the grid like so:

```
$("#mainGrid").jqGrid({
    url : g_MainGridUrl,
    datatype : 'json',
    height : 460,
    autowidth : true,
    colNames : g_ColNames,
    colModel : g_ColModel,
    pager : '#pager',
    rowNum : 100,
    rowList : [100, 200, 300],
    sortname : g_DefaultSort,
    sortorder : 'desc',
    sortable: true,
    viewrecords : true,
    caption : 'Results',
    hidegrid : false,
    rownumbers : true,          
    jsonReader : {
        root : "ROWS",
        page : "PAGE",
        total : "TOTAL",
        records : "RECORDS",
        cell : "",
        id : g_DefaultSort
    },
    loadComplete: function(){
        var num_records = $('#mainGrid').getGridParam('records');
        $('#gview_mainGrid div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar span').html('Results: '+num_records);
    },
    loadBeforeSend : function(thisXhr) {
        xhr = thisXhr;
    },
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
        jQuery(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid, { width: "500"});
    }
});

$("#mainGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    del : false,
    add : false,
    edit : false,
    refresh:false,
    search: false,
    view: true
});

$("#mainGrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{
    caption: "Columns",
    title: "Reorder Columns",
    onClickButton : function (){
        $("#mainGrid").jqGrid("columnChooser", {
            done: function() {
                resize_the_grid();
            },
            height: 320
        });
    }
});
```

and calling the grid like so, after building a filter Object:

```
$('#mainGrid').setGridParam({
        url : g_MainGridUrl + Ext.util.JSON.encode(filter)
    });
$('#mainGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");
```

As the subject states, when I double-click on a row to view its record and then change rows from the modal dialog, not all columns get updated - some do, but not others. I thought it might be because I didn't have <th>s defined for the table, so I tried adding them. I have downloaded the most recent version (4.2.0). There are no errors shown. This is true in IE8, Chrome, Safari. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I think I've found the cause, but still don't have a solution. It seems that any column that has a title with a space in the name can't read the grid correctly. I confirmed by adding underscores to replace the spaces in the titles, and found that for each column corrected, its values began updating. I'm filing a bug report at Trirand.

UPDATE 2: It seems there already was a bug report filed:
[trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-in-viewgridrow-with-spaces-in-column-name/#p25613) - however, the author doesn't consider it a bug, but rather expects developers to not use column headers with spaces, as jqgrid builds IDs based on the names in the column model. I've requested that this behavior be changed but expect I'll have to dig around in his code to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the developer has decided that column names may not have spaces (not sure if this is mentioned anywhere in the documentation), I fixed it by hacking the jqgrid source code. Inside the viewGridRow() function, add this line:

```
nm = nm.replace(' ', '_');
```

in two places; first between these two lines in function createData():

```
nm = this.name;
setme = false;
```

second, between these two lines in function fillData():

```
nm = obj.p.colModel[i].name;
// hidden fields are included in the form
```

Now, all ids are created with underscores in the place of spaces and all is well.